# Rust: Convert a mutable u8 pointer to a mutable reference

Tags: pointers, rust, types, casting

How can I convert a mutable u8 pointer to a mutable reference of another type?

```rs
let ptr: *mut u8;

let reference: &mut SomeType = ?; // What should i do here?
```

I have found a sort-of viable solution, but I wonder if there is a better way:

```rs
let reference = unsafe { &mut *(ptr as *mut SomeType) };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already found an acceptable method. A slightly preferable one is to use [`pointer::cast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast-1) instead of `as`, because that explicitly specifies that you are trying to *change the type of the referent* and not any of the many other things `as` can do.

```rust
let ptr = ptr.cast::<SomeType>();
let reference = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
```

---

Do not use `std::mem::transmute` for this. Transmuting should always be the *last resort* in any circumstance (the [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html) and [function documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) say so!), because it reinterprets the bytes regardless of what they are — in this case it'll convert any pointer-sized value, such as a reference to the pointer. By sticking with `cast` and `&*`, we catch more possible type errors. ([Clippy even has a default lint against using transmute here.](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#transmute_ptr_to_ref))

Comment: Thank you very much!
In the end, I used `.as_mut()` to convert the pointer to a reference, but I will also replace `as` with `cast`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::mem::transmute` instead:

```rust
use std::mem::transmute;
#[repr(transparent)]
struct SomeStruct(u8);

fn main() {
    let a = &mut 10u8;
    let ptr = a as *mut u8;
    let reference: &mut SomeStruct = unsafe { transmute(ptr) };
}
```